# Close review - drastically edited question

Tags: discussion

I'm reviewing [Switch Statement Inside a method of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23707423/switch-statement-inside-a-method-of-another-class) in the Close Vote queue.

As originally posted, it contained a simple and uninteresting typo sort of problem, and was closed, in my opinion correctly, for that reason. It has now been edited. The edit dealt with the issues that had been raised in comments and answers, making the answers to the original question meaningless in the context of the edited version.

I voted to reopen it. Other reviewers have looked at it, and voted to leave it closed, suggesting I was wrong to vote to reopen. What should be done with a drastically edited question?

Note that the current comment on the question says "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question or leave a comment.", suggesting that editing the question is a legitimate action.

The syntax error did not relate to the actual question, but needed to be cleared up to make sure of that.

Comment: All the edit did was remove the majority of the switch cases.

Comment: It's more of a RTFM question.  Not sure why one would reopen it.

Comment: Am I going crazy, or should that edit actually be rolled back because it fixed the problem?

Comment: @hichris123 The edit fixed an incidental problem that needed to be cleared up, but the original question remains unanswered.

Comment: ... [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23707441/25818720) seems to say otherwise. I'd agree with the answer, and I'd think that it should fix the problem.

Comment: @hichris123 is right. Both answers solve the issue (although they could have been a bit more expansive, IMO) and the attempted *edit* solved the issue right from the start -- through applying the suggested answers --, so there wouldn't have been a question left.

Comment: I believe you were right to reopen. I'm wondering if the original close votes, and subsequent re-close votes actually took the time to read and understand the question, and relate it to the answers.

Answer (score 4):

"The edit made the answers to the original question irrelevant, therefore I voted to re-open"

To me such a change would suggest a new question, not a re-opened one, unless there were no answers and the only comments were what do you mean?

Comment: Not if there simply a misunderstanding of what the original question was. One question I've asked on StackOverflow elicited several irrelevant answers. It wasn't until I edited emphasizing the actual information I was seeking, that someone finally worked together an answer to the question. It happens.

Comment: On the other hand I've had a couple where the person involved used my answer, then edited their original question with a follow on and some nerk marked me down because my answer down as it was irrelevant. I found that 'erm irritating...